# Get URL from XML node with xmllint, add new line

Tags: linux, bash, xmllint

I am extracting URL's from a XML file with this command:

```
xmllint --xpath '//ROOT/ITEM/PHOTO/text()' xml_2015-05-13-20\:39.xml
```

It works, but output is a mass text of URL's:

```
http://1.jpghttp://2.jpghttp://3.jpghttp://4.jpghttp://5.jpghttp://6.jpg
```

It is possible to add `\n` new line character after each match?

XML:

```
<ROOT>
   <ITEM>
      <PHOTO>http://1.jpg</PHOTO>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <PHOTO>http://2.jpg</PHOTO>
   </ITEM>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: `//ROOT` is silly -- that means you're searching the whole tree for other roots. One would think that, inherently, there would only ever be one root, so you should be able to use `/ROOT`, and make your search much more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible way to do that whit xidel:

```
xidel -e "//ROOT/ITEM/PHOTO/text()" -q ./my.xml > ./processed_xml
```

Comment: And pluse uno to @Adrian for struggling thru to his own answer. ;-! ( just realized that this Answer is from the O.P. Doah!)  BUT ... could you update your question with a small set of XML as we would find in `xml_2015-05-13-20\:39.xml`? Thanks and  good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Get [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net)  and try

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/ROOT/ITEM/PHOTO" -v . -n xml_2015-05-13-20\:39.xml 
            |   |  |                     |    |
            |   |  |                     |    -n ... add new-line after printed element
            |   |  |                     -v .  print the value of the matched node
            |   |  -m match this Xpath
            |   -t  (select) using a template (the -m part)
            sel(ect)
```

xmlstarlet is designed for cmd-line processing and scripting solutions, where as xmllint does not list such uses as a top priority.

Comment: I've worked thru about 1/3 of the samples in the XMLStarlet doc today. Is there anything else I should be working thru to really get this?

Comment: Not that I know of; I mostly picked up my knowledge of the tool through (quite a lot of) trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

With `xmllint` itself it is not possible, as others already stated.

But with help from tools like `sed` you could achive what you want:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "//ROOT/ITEM/PHOTO" xml_2015-05-13-20\:39.xml | sed "s/<\/PHOTO>/<\/PHOTO>\n/g"
<PHOTO>http://1.jpg</PHOTO>
<PHOTO>http://2.jpg</PHOTO>
```

now to get rid of the tags an additional expression is required:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "//ROOT/ITEM/PHOTO" xml_2015-05-13-20\:39.xml | sed "s/<\/PHOTO>/<\/PHOTO>\n/g ; s/<[^>]\+>//g"
http://1.jpg
http://2.jpg
```